# sequential containers and iterators arithmetic

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

I'm studying the sequential containers library and something made me think.

I had given for granted that every container, except special cases, like forward_list, where it's not possible in one direction, fully supports iterator arithmetic. Instead I just found out that the generic container supports only a very specific set of operations: * and -> (for obvious reasons), pre and post-increment and decrement (not 100% sure about post) and equality/inequality relational operators. More complex arithmetic is reserved for vectors, string and deque.

I don't understand this constraint. What are the reasons we are prohibited from, for example, subtracting between two iterators or adding an int to an iterator? After all, if we have access to pre/post-increment/decrement we can easily, even though inefficiently, implement addition and subtraction by repeatedly iterating those operations with an integer counter.

Comment: You answered your own question: _"... we can easily, even though inefficiently ..."_ .  If you want to do this you can but the standard containers are trying to let you know that this is possibly a bad idea.

Comment: There are different [iterator categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator). On non-random-access iterators, arithmetic is disabled (probably) because it would often have non-constant complexity and could slow down your program if used incorrectly. To do arithmetic on arbitrary iterators, use `std::next`, `std::prev`, `std::advance`, `std::distance`, etc.

Comment: "easily, even though inefficiently" that's exactly the key. C++ doesn't want inefficient things to be easily confused with efficient things.

Comment: You may also want to know about [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), [std::prev](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev), [std::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) & [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) for nice generic solutions that don't involve direct pointer/iterator arithmetic. Just saying.

Answer (score 6):

The missing inefficient operations you mentioned are in fact available, offered by `std::distance` and `std::advance`. (There's also `std::prev` and `std::next`, for more subtle reasons.)

The reason not to require all iterators, or at least all bidirectional iterators, to support things like `operator+=`, is to warn users that they're doing something that's not as efficient as they might expect it to be. It's easy to write something like `*(iter+offset)` in a loop, later change the container type from a `std::vector` to a `std::set`, and not notice that you've accidentally turned an `O(n)` operation into an `O(n^2)` one.

Comment: +1. I suspect it's also possible via template metaprogramming to choose different algorithms depending on whether a caller-supplied iterator directly supports some operation or not.

Comment: @davmac Yep. `std::distance`, for example, is constant-time for random access iterators, using `std::iterator_traits` to decide what kind of an iterator it's looking at. That was one of the original uses of template metaprogramming and partial template specialization.

Comment: @davmac there (usually) is no need to. The metaprogramming has already been done within `std::next` etc.

Comment: @davmac to expand on my previous comment: An example of case where you would need template meta programming would be to distinguish non-forward input iterators. For example, if you wanted to copy a range into a container, and have the ability to pre-reserve the memory depending on the length of the range, it would be syntactically valid to use `std::distance`, but logically wrong for non-forward iterators, since you could no longer do the copy, because non-forward iterators are not guaranteed to allow multiple passes. I would expect an implementation of a vector to do something to check this.

Comment: @user2079303 my point was that it is possible to distinguish the iterator capabilities and have different implementations of an algorithm or function depending on their capability (It doesn't matter if that's done by the user or in the standard library implementation, as far as I'm concerned).

Answer (score 2):

You've mentioned the reason within your question:

> ... even though inefficiently ...

It is a good design, to not perform computationally complex (usually linear or worse) operations in operators. This design allows the users of the API to assume that addition and subtraction operations have constant complexity without needing to know the specification of that operation. If such assumption were false, the programmer could easily end up writing programs that have worse asymptotic complexity than they intended.

Such linear operations exist in the form of `std::next`, `std::distance` etc. Programmers don't (or shouldn't) make assumptions about complexity of a function call without knowing the specification of that function.

---

If you disagree with the design of the standard library, you can write an iterator adaptor, which adds the missing operator overloads, and use that.

Comment: The standard does specify complexity of quite a few "function calls".   Including `std::next()` (linear complexity), and quite a few standard algorithms.   The programmer is allowed, by definition, to assume the implementations comply with that specification.

Comment: @Peter a programmer can indeed assume that an implementation complies with its specification. I intended to convey that programmer can / or can't make assumptions without context. A specification is an example of such context. I'll try to make that more clear.